# Here's what I've learned so far but it's not working: RE CSS, HTML, JS and making buttons toggle

Tags: javascript, html, css

I got this advice:

http://jsfiddle.net/Tpz86/16/

The Javascript:

```
function classToggle() {
    this.classList.toggle('on');
    this.classList.toggle('off');
}
document.querySelector('.onoff').addEventListener('click', classToggle);
```

The HTML:

```
<img class="on onoff" src='http://s29.postimg.org/xc5u3fufn/image.png' />

<img class="on onoff" src='http://s29.postimg.org/xc5u3fufn/image.png' />
```

The CSS:

```
.on {
    opacity: 1.0;
}

.off {
    opacity:0.0;
}
.onoff {   
}
```

But only one of the two buttons toggles on and off. Why is that? They both have the non-unique-required CLASS identifiers 'onoff' which should make them referenced by JS as toggling between also having class ON or OFF respectively, right?

Side question: Do I have to define the class .onoff in CSS if it essentially does nothing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`querySelector` returns the first match. You want `querySelectorAll` to find all matches.

That said, you will have to loop through returned elements.

```
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll(".onoff"),function(e) {
    e.addEventListener("click",classToggle);
});
```

Comment: Deleted sorry about that.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Tpz86/16/

I'm not sure what you mean here because I'm super duper new to CSS and have zero training in JS. 

What it looks like you're saying is that I need to take what I have in the link above and modify it thus: 

    '[function classToggle() {
    this.classList.toggle('on');
    this.classList.toggle('off'); 
    }     
    document.querySelector('.onoff').addEventListener('click', classToggle);].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll(".onoff"),function(e) {
    e.addEventListener("click",classToggle);
});'

Comment: how do i make 'code' work in these comments?! argh so frustrating

Comment: Just take the code I gave you, throw it in, and amazingly [it works](http://jsfiddle.net/Tpz86/18/)!

Comment: Oh my gosh you are my hero. How do I give you points?

Alternately and additionally if you ever want some graphics made send me the details. You've been an amazing help sir or ma'am.

Comment: Just hit that check mark next to my answer ;) You may want to put some samples of your work on your profile, so people like me can take a look :3

Comment: Well if you think of something I can do it, no need for obligations to use the work, just try me out if you have a specific need and if you don't like the result I won't be offended; art is really subjective unlike coding, not everyone likes what they see... but here's my last project, an HUD for a League of Legends pro, but it's only about half done, gonna add skulls/bones/claw marks/a bunch more tiny details before the job's done.

http://s28.postimg.org/6k7u9rrkt/UI_SEMIFINAL.png

http://s24.postimg.org/5triz3i2d/ui_semifinal_context.png

Answer (score 0):

`querySelector` returns the *first* element that matches the selector you pass to it.

If you want to get multiple elements, then you need to use `querySelectorAll` which will return a *NodeList* rather than an *HTMLElementNode* which you will have to loop over like an *Array*.

Alternatively, add your event listener to an element that is an ancestor of both images, and then test to see if the image was clicked on.

```
someElement.addEventListener('click', function (evt) {
    var el = evt.target;
    if (el.classList.contains('onoff')) {
        el.classList.toggle('on');
        el.classList.toggle('off');
    }
});
```